# Jacoco code coverage report is showing zero in AOSP junit testing

Tags: android-source, jacoco, robolectric, android.mk

I am working in AOSP for automotive and in Junit test I can get coverage report using Jacoco but it is zero everytime even after tests successfully run. Please help me on this. I am doing this with AOSP, Robolectric library and Jacoco.

expecting to get coverage report with proper percentage.

I am using Android.mk and Robolectric.